# What would be a good way of looping through an API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api

I'm trying to figure out a good way to loop through an array and so far I've only been able to figure out how to get through one at a time. I'm assuming that I need to make a forEach statement, but not exactly sure how to word said statement. Do any of you happen to know a good way of doing this?

Below is my node.js app file with the API key removed

```
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/" + yyyy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd + "/schedule.json?api_key=", function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: (data["games"][6]["home"]["name"]) + " Vs " + (data["games"][6]["away"]["name"]) }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data);
});
       }
  });
```

Here is an example of the array that I'm trying to loop through:

games:

```
  [ { id: 'f46c9795-a8f1-4ca3-8960-3788fb6a37c5',
       status: 'scheduled',
       coverage: 'extended_boxscore',
       scheduled: '2017-02-28T00:00:00+00:00',
       conference_game: true,
       venue: [Object],
       broadcast: [Object],
       home: [Object],
       away: [Object] },
     { id: '0e93d1d1-2d57-4524-b95f-d9d1b133b95f',
       status: 'scheduled',
       coverage: 'full',
       scheduled: '2017-02-28T00:00:00+00:00',
       conference_game: true,
       venue: [Object],
       broadcast: [Object],
       home: [Object],
       away: [Object] },
     { id: '7eb44074-4656-489a-976d-abfcbd669a7c',
       status: 'scheduled',
       coverage: 'extended_boxscore',
       scheduled: '2017-02-28T00:00:00+00:00',
       conference_game: true,
       venue: [Object],
       home: [Object],
       away: [Object] },
     { id: '76fed39a-f931-4243-885d-86b14da93e4a',
       title: 'Atlantic Sun - Quarterfinal 3',
       status: 'scheduled',
       coverage: 'full',
       scheduled: '2017-02-28T00:00:00+00:00',
       conference_game: false,
       venue: [Object],
       broadcast: [Object],
       home: [Object],
       away: [Object] },
```

as you can see I have a number [6] inputted for both the home and away teams, as it's the only way that it seems to work for me, otherwise it gives me an error because it's an object if I just write it like this (`data["games"]["home"]["name"]`) any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should show what home and away holds.

Comment: @baao it's just the names of the teams

Comment: No it's not, it's an object

Comment: @baao ok, so how do I get it to show what it is, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Well yes, but I also have problems understanding what you want to do with the data.

Comment: @baao right now I'm just wanting to console log it so I can see how it works, but eventually I'm building an app. What you are seeing is a twitter post with the information in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as for your comments, to just loop through the games and show the away team against the home team, the following will work:

```
data.games.forEach(v => {
    console.log("home team: " + v.home.name, "away team: " + v.away.name);
});
```

Of course you can use the same loop to post multiple status updates to twitter...

I'm not aware of the twitter API and don't know if there's a possibility to post multiple updates in a single call, but to simply post multiple times you could use that:

```
data.games.forEach(v => {
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: v.home.name + " VS " + v.away.name }, 
        function(err, data, response) {
            // ... handle the response as you like
        }
});
```

---

```
data.games.forEach((v,i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        T.post('statuses/update', { status: v.home.name + " VS " + v.away.name },
            function(err, data, response) {
                // ... handle the response as you like
            });
    }, i * 20000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, can you explain this segment and what I was doing wrong? Or maybe post a good resource for me to look at to help? If not that's cool too, thank you for the help!

Comment: Well it's basically only a forEach loop, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The `v` in the loop is the object - and home, away (and home.name) and so on are properties of the object. What you have as a response is an array of objects, you can find quite a lot of information about that when you google for array of objects - there are also some Q & A about that here on SO. @Branduo

Comment: P.S. You can access a certain array element by its index (that's what you did with data.games[6] - or you can loop over the entire array like I did in the answer @Branduo

Comment: thank you for your help, I'm self taught so trial and error seem to be my best friend, but sometimes I get stuck and then nice people like you can explain things easier than documentation to me. Thanks again.

Comment: one more thing, I just ran a setInterval function and tweeted all my data at one time LOL how would I loop through each object but not all at once maybe once every 20 seconds? And then I need to end it after it has looped through all of them once.

Comment: Edited the answer to do that. The second parameter for forEach, (the `i` in this case), is the current index. So simply multiply the index with 20000 (ms) and you will post the first one immediatly and then every 20 seconds a new post. @Branduo

Comment: @baoo after trying to run that code for some reason it is still running it all at once.

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error in the code. Can you copy the newly edited and try again please @Branduo

Comment: WOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!! got it, where was the syntax error? I figured that's what it was but couldn't find it myself.

Comment: I've just forgot a closing `)`... @Branduo . In the code above right above the 20000